# How to filter dictionary for keys with multiple items in a list for value

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, filter

I have a dictionary with a key-value pair consisting of a key and a value that consists of one or multiple elements of a list.  I am looking for a way to filter the dictionary to only include the keys with multiple list elements (more than one).

Example:

```
dictX = {'cat': [0], 'dog': [1], 'bird': [2,2,2], 'fish': [3,4]}
```

I want to filter so that the new dictionary would only have 'bird' and 'fish' as key value pairs, while dropping the ones with a single element in the list value.

Comment: Do you specifically need to drop items from the _existing_ dictionary?  It's usually much easier to make a _new_ dictionary that has only the items you want.

Comment: The solution provided below works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use a dict comprehension and len:

```
dictY = {key: val for key, val in dictX.items() if len(val) > 1}
```